# Relay sizing to drive DC motor

Tags: relay, dc-motor

I'd like to use a relay to switch on and off a standard 12 V DC motor, which is 6 W according to its specification. A 2 A relay looks good on paper, but will it be able to deal with the surge of current when it switches on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, motors are like capacitors - big inrush current. size the relay to handle the stall current or risk welding the contacts closed.

Comment: Thanks. Would connecting a thermistor in series solve this possible issue? I am thinking something like a 15 R, 1.8 A steady state current one.

Comment: a resistor is going to make the motor weaker, why do you not want a big relay?

Comment: I have a limited amount of power to switch the relay, and space is also limited. I'll try if the motor can do what I want and if not, I can still modify the circuit.

Comment: NTC thermistor might work. but they get hot.